# regex re.compile multiline or block of text with quotes "

Tags: python, regex, maya

i'm trying to replace many block of text in some .ma files with regex in with python :
the old paragraphe to modify begin with:

```
setAttr ".os"
```

and ending with:

```
setAttr ".sf"
```

i need to modify this block with this part:

(numbers are going to be variables and i doesn't want to remove blanks, commas, quotes and newlines)

```
setAttr ".os" 80;
setAttr ".oe" 358;
setAttr ".ss" 80;
setAttr ".se" 358;
setAttr ".sf"
```

i had tryed this part:

```
import os, glob, fnmatch, re

firstFrame = str(101)       
lastFrame = str(200) 

begin = 'setAttr ".os" '
ending = 'setAttr ".sf" '

newAtrrs = """
    setAttr ".os" """+ firstFrame +""";
    setAttr ".oe" """+ firstFrame +""";
    setAttr ".ss" """+ lastFrame +""";
    setAttr ".se" """+ lastFrame +""";
    setAttr ".sf"
    """      
print  begin
#result: setAttr ".os" 
print  ending
#result: setAttr ".sf" 
print  newAtrrs
#result: 
#    setAttr ".os" 101;
#    setAttr ".oe" 101;
#    setAttr ".ss" 200;
#    setAttr ".se" 200;
#    setAttr ".sf"

ShotScene = 'C:\\Users\\manue\\Desktop\\ShotTest.ma'
output_file = '{0}'.format(ShotScene).replace("/","\\") 

with open(output_file, "r") as read_stream:
    lines=read_stream.read()
    print lines
    #result:
    '''
    //Maya ASCII 2014 scene
    blablabla
    createNode cacheFile -n "FCHCache1";
        setAttr ".cn" -type "string" "FCH";
        setAttr ".cp" -type "string" "V506/001/166/ANI/";
        setAttr ".ch[0]" -type "string" "vin02:hairLowerShape";
        setAttr ".os" 80;
        setAttr ".oe" 358;
        setAttr ".ss" 80;
        setAttr ".se" 358;
        setAttr ".sf" 80;
    createNode historySwitch -n "cacheSwitch2";
        setAttr ".ch[0]" -type "string" "hairLowerShape";
        setAttr ".os" 80;
        setAttr ".oe" 358;
        setAttr ".ss" 80;
        setAttr ".se" 358;
        setAttr ".sf" 80;
    createNode historySwitch -n "cacheSwitch2";
        setAttr ".ihi" 0;
    blablabla
    '''   
    with open(output_file, "w") as write_stream:
        oldAtrrs = re.findall(r""+begin+"(.*?)\s(.*?)\s"+ending+"")
        regex = re.compile(oldAtrrs, re.MULTILINE)
        write_stream.write(regex.sub(newAtrrs, lines))
```

As i had tryed many times without any luck, any help is welcome,
thank you

Comment: Why not use NP++, do you really need Python to do this ?

Comment: Also, it's hard to try your code in Python since the input is unknown, or is it ? You should break this down to something simpler that can be seen and understood more easily. I see a short regex that is constructed `""+begin+"(.*?)\s(.*?)\s"+ending+""` would be nice to print that out as a string before giving it to findall(). If you're having problems, you have to break the problem down.

Comment: yes, you're right my question isn't very clear, so i reedit it, and everything is ok, except from this line:    oldAtrrs = re.findall(r""+begin+"(.*?)\s(.*?)\s"+ending+"")     as i don't know how to to find a block of text to modify it....

Comment: and i need to do it in python because i run it inside a 3d software, and i don't know  NP++ also

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and i had change of method:

```
import os,glob

firstFrame = str(101)       
lastFrame = str(200) 

begin = 'setAttr ".os" '
ending = 'setAttr ".sf" '

test = """setAttr ".os" """+ firstFrame +""";
    setAttr ".oe" """+ lastFrame +""";
    setAttr ".ss" """+ firstFrame +""";
    setAttr ".se" """+ lastFrame +""";
    setAttr ".sf" """ 
    
ShotScene = 'C:\\Users\\manue\\Desktop\\ShotTest.ma'
filename = '{0}'.format(ShotScene).replace("/","\\") 
                           
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    # read entire file into file1
    file1 = f.read()

    # index() will raise an error if not found
    f1_start = file1.index(begin)
    f1_end = file1.index(ending, f1_start)     

    key = file1[f1_start:(f1_end+13)] # 25 is the length of the string 'http://www.blahdeblah.com' 
    file1 = file1.replace(key, test )

    with open(filename+'_Reut', 'w') as f:
        f.write(file1)
```

with replace() that's working perfect!
thanks  Maxt8r for your advices :)